# Converting a string to to date using Python and datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column that contains stings in the form 'yyyymmdd' as below;

```
Start_date
20081201
20120823
20101210
```

I want to  be able to convert these into actual dates and am looking at using `datetime`. From looking online I have managed to get to define both of the following functions.

```
def dateconvert(Start_date):
    dateconv = datetime.strptime(Start_date, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    return  dateconv

def get_datetime(date_string):
    newdate = datetime.date(date_string[:3],date_string[4:6],date_string[6:8])
    return newdate
```

I have then tried applying these using the `apply` function as below

```
 Dates['Newdates'] = Dates['Start_date'].apply(get_datetime)
```

However I keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Even though the values in the fields are Integers!

Comment: It may be constructive to troubleshoot your functions on built-in Python types before trying to use them in tandem with numpy. For instance, what do you expect `get_datetime(20081201)` to return, and what does it actually return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the date to a string first.

```
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.strptime(str(20081201), '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Will return

```
'12/01/2008'
```

Answer (score 0):

The full solution I used was the following

```
import datetime as dt

def dateconvert(Start_date):
    Date_String = str(Start_date)
    dateconv = dt.datetime.strptime(Date_String, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    return  dateconv

Dates['Newdates'] = Dates['Start_date'].apply(dateconvert)
```